# How To Solve For p in this equation?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How do I solve for p in the following equation:

$50,000=\frac{25000p}{100-p}$ ?

Thanks!!

Comment: Is this $=25000\cdot \frac{p}{100} - p$ or is this $=\frac{25000\cdot p}{100-p}$?  If you don't use parenthesis, it is interpreted as the first.  Remember that parenthesis are important.  Have you tried simplifying the fraction if its the first or multiplying both sides of the equation by the bottom of the fraction if its the second?

Comment: It is the second one 50000=(25000*p)/(100-p).

Comment: Please add some more about what you've tried next time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By cross Multiplication you get

$50,000(100-p)=25,000p$

$50,00000 - 50,000p = 25,000p$

$50,00000 = 75,000p$

$p= 50,00000 / 75,000$

$p=66.66$ Approximately

Comment: In mathematics, we generally use equals signs only if things are in fact *equal*.  $p=\frac{5000000}{75000}\Rightarrow p=\frac{200}{3}=66+\frac{2}{3}\neq 66+\frac{66}{100}=66.66$.  Either leave things in exact form or mention that it is an approximation for a final result.

Comment: @JMoravitz edited mate

Comment: Thanks guys, you answered my question!

Answer (score 2):

Notice, $$50000=\frac{25000p}{100-p}$$ $$2=\frac{p}{100-p}$$ $\color{red}{\text{cross multiplication}}$ $$2(100-p)=p$$ $$200-2p=p$$ $$p+2p=200$$ $$3p=200$$ $$\bbox[5px, border:2px solid #C0A000]{\color{red}{p=\frac{200}{3}\approx66.67}}$$ $

Comment: Thank you for helping. I like this site people answer so quickly!